# como fazer um inner join pegando a descricao

Tags: mysql, sql, join

minhas tabelas:

```
agencias (id, nome_agencia, ads -> FK pra tabela de baixo)
ads (id, nome, agencia -> essa é FK pra tabela anterior)
```

o problema é assim: cada agencia vai ter um ads
no ads tem uma agencia principal

quero fazer um select exibindo agencia_id, agencia_nome, ads_id, ads_nome_da_agencia

tentei assim, mas nao sei como "encaixar" o nome da agencia

```
SELECT agencias.id as id_agencia, agencias.nome as agencia_nome, ads.id as id_ads, ads.agencia as ads_agencia_id
FROM agencias
INNER JOIN ads
ON agencias.id=ads.agencia
```

Answer (score 2):

Você só precisa dar um "apelido" para suas tabelas

```
SELECT 
    ag.id as id_agencia, 
    ag.nome as agencia_nome, 
    ad.id as id_ads, 
    ad.agencia as ads_agencia_id
FROM 
    agencias ag
INNER JOIN ads ad ON ad.id = ag.ads -- ag.ads = FK ads -> agencia
```

Comment: executando essa query me resultou no seguinte: id_agencia, agencia_nome, id_ads, ads_agencia_id ...... eu preciso tb que me retorne o nome da agencia q está referenciado no ads_agencia_id

Comment: Basta referenciá-la no select. `ad.nome`, onde `ad` é o apelido que foi definido para  a tabela e em seguida o nome do campo. Você irá fazer dessa maneira para adicionar todos os campos que desejar.